# R lattice package: add legend to a figure

Tags: r, legend, lattice

I am using the lattice package, and I want to add a **legend** to my figure. The documentation of **auto.key** and **legend** is very confusing, and couldn;t figure out the correct syntax to add a legend. Here is my code:

```
xyplot(y ~ x, df, pch=19, col=rgb(0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 0.7), cex=2,
       scales=list(cex=1.7),
       xlab=list("x", cex=1.ales=list(cex=1.7),
       xlab=list("x", cex=1.7), ylab=list("y", cex=1.7),
       main=list("Linear Regression w. Polynomial Attributes", cex=1.6),
       auto.key=T,
       panel = function(x, y, ...) {
            panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
            llines(x, predict(lm.xtend), col="purple", lwd=6, lty=3)
            llines(x, predict(ridge.lin), col="darkgreen", lwd=6, lty=2)
       })
```

The graph is shown below, so I just want to add a legend for the lines. 
[image]

Comment: The `legend`-function is not part of the grid/lattice/ggplot world. You are trying to mix base-graphics with grid-graphics. In lattice it would need to be `legend=list('inside' = someGrobMakingFunction)`. You should learn to use the `key=list...)` mechanism.

Comment: Still no example, so it remains unclear what you were hoping to see. There are no group or conditioning variables in that `xyplot`-call so it remains unclear how a legend with two text values is supposed to be constructed. Perhaps you just want to add a text box?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't know exactly how you want this to look, but here is a start. In place of `auto.key=T` put:

```
key=list(space="right",
         lines=list(col=c("purple","darkgreen"), lty=c(3,2), lwd=6),
         text=list(c("Purple Line"," Dark-green Line"))
)
```

This will put the key on the right side of the graph. You can use "top", "bottom", or "left"  instead. If you want it inside the plot, get rid of `space` and instead use `corner=c(0,1)`. The first number is location on the x-axis (from 0 to 1) the second for the y-axis. So this would put in in the upper left.